# An error ocurred while starting the kernel . I think because of two python version but unable to figure out

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, anaconda

I am trying to fit a model here but thing is that every time I fit a model my kernel dies I tried every other method but it did't worked.

I think there may be possibility of having two python versions installed but I don't know how to fix that or even verify that.

Also I am using MAC

I have tried updating reinstalling everything

```
#Importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder,StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,cross_val_score
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier



#Importing Datasets
dataset=pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X=dataset.iloc[:,3:13].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,13].values


#Data preprocessing
le1=LabelEncoder()
X[:,1]=le1.fit_transform(X[:,1])
le2=LabelEncoder()
X[:,2]=le2.fit_transform(X[:,2])
h1=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1])
X=h1.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X=X[:,1:]


#Splitting Dataset
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)


#Feature Scaling
sc=StandardScaler()
X_train=sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=sc.transform(X_test)


#Making ANN hidden layer

classifier=keras.models.Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(units=6,activation="relu",kernel_initializer="uniform",input_shape=(11,)))

#Adding second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=6,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))

#Adding output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer='uniform'))

#Compiling ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

> Till here it works like a charm with some warnings

```
#Making predictions and evaluating it
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=10)
```

> But when  I execute this it shows

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
b''
```

Any one knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help you: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2812

If you are using Spyder, try:

```
conda update setuptools
```

Comment: not worked tried `# All requested packages already installed.` but still not working

Comment: If you are using Anaconda, try running the following from the Anaconda prompt or reinstalling Anaconda

'conda update spyder ipykernel tornado pyzmq'